# Exception property in ActionExecutedContext from WebAPI filter is null

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-3.0

I have been using the same exception filter for a couple of months now, and it had performed perfectly up until now. Here it is:

```
public class HttpResponseExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order { get; set; } = int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException exception)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(new {Mensagem = context.Exception.Message})
            {
                StatusCode = exception.Status,
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else if (context.Exception is Exception)
        {
            var message = context.Exception.InnerException != null ? context.Exception.InnerException.Message : context.Exception.Message;

            context.Result = new ObjectResult(new RetornoExceptionApi(message))
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            };

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Simple and straight-forward. I've been using it to catch custom HTTP exceptions which `HttpResponseException` is the base class. This is what it looks like:

```
public class HttpResponseException : Exception
{
    public int Status { get; set; } = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

    public HttpResponseException(int statusCode)
    {
        Status = statusCode;
    }
}
```

Nothing to it. This is my custom exception for a 404 status code:

```
public class NotFoundException404<TKey> : HttpResponseException
{
    private string _message;

    public NotFoundException404(TKey id) : base(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    {
        _message = $"Nenhum objeto encontrado! ID solicitado: { id }";
    }
    public NotFoundException404(long id) : base(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    {
        _message = $"Nenhum objeto encontrado! ID solicitado: { id }";
    }
    public NotFoundException404(string message) : base(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    {
        _message = message;
    }

    public override string Message => _message;
}
```

Sample usage (this is from my base service class):

```
    protected virtual async Task<TEntity> GetWithFilterAsync(TKey id)
    {
        var entidade = await _repository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(GetFiltroListar(id));

        if (entidade == null)
            throw new NotFoundException404<TKey>(id);

        return entidade;
    }
```

Like I said, this works just fine, the filter even catches exceptions raised from within the framework. But I had to create a custom exception to handle foreign key violations and whenever I throw this exception, the filter's `OnActionExecuted` is called, but `context.Exception` is null. Here's the custom exception:

```
public class ForeignKeyViolationException : Exception
{
    public override string Message => "Registro possui dependências e não pode ser excluído";

    public ForeignKeyViolationException() : base() { }

    public ForeignKeyViolationException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

This exception is raised from the same base service as the HTTP other ones, as such:

```
    protected async Task DeleteAsync(TKey id)
    {
        var entidade = await GetEntidadeExclusaoAsync(id);
        try
        {
            await _repository.DeleteAsync(entidade);
        }
        catch (SqlException e) when (e.Number == 547)
        {
            throw new ForeignKeyViolationException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null
                && ex is SqlException
                && ((SqlException)ex).Number == 547)
                throw new ForeignKeyViolationException();
        }
    }
```

That doesn't work (`Exception` is `null` in my filter) and I have no idea why. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here seems to be that I'm pretty stupid. I stop to inspect the code in a more thoroughly manner, and the problem isn't in the filters, but how I tried to raise the `ForeignKeyViolationException`. This:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null
            && ex is SqlException
            && ((SqlException)ex).Number == 547)
            throw new ForeignKeyViolationException();
    }
```

should be this:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null
            && ex.InnerException is SqlException
            && ((SqlException)ex.InnerException).Number == 547)
            throw new ForeignKeyViolationException();
        else
            throw ex;
    }
```

"Derp!"

**UPDATE**

johnny 5's answer is cleaner and works perfectly, it surely is the preferred way of doing it:

```
catch (Exception ex) when ((ex.InnerException as SqlException)?.Number == 547)
{
    throw new ForeignKeyViolationException();
}
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake, (SqlException.InnerException)ex) should probably read like this: ((SqlException)ex.InnerException).  See my answers for optimizations and improved readability

Comment: @johnny5 Yeah, I screwed up while passing the code over, just updated my answer. I'm gonna give yours a try (looks solid) and update it once more after testing it. I didn't know you could use `when` like that. In fact I didn't know `when` at all up until last week

Comment: LOL there you go. BTW, you missed a couple of parenthesis, the compiler allows only `when ((ex.InnerException as SqlException)?.Number == 547)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found the answer to your question already.  However I'll make an effort to built on your answer.  You can use a when clause to make the function more readable.

```
catch (Exception ex) when ((ex.InnerException as SqlException)?.Number == 547) {
    throw new ForeignKeyViolationException();
}
```